# rpm install file exist issue

Tags: dependencies, rpm

There is a question about install rpm.
When I install rpm file

```
rpm -ivh myrpm.rpm
```

sytem wil show

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by myrpm
```

but when I check system using locate

```
locate libapr-1.so.0
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.3.9
```

file seems exist

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you my thoughts, I see two possible scenarios here:

A) You did not install /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 via RPM, so RPM would not have any record of it in its package database.  RPM only knows about files that were properly installed via an RPM package.  This can be checked by asking RPM where it thinks those files came from:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.3.9
```

B) You are installing something that requires the 64bit version of libapr-1.so.0 and you only have the 32bit version installed (/usr/lib is normally where all the 32bit or noarch stuff is stored for RedHat/Fedora/Centos, /usr/lib64 would have the 64bit libraries).  Unless you have a 64bit system, you should probably be installing 32bit RPMs.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello.
I've the same issue with a package listed in rpm.

error:

libXss.so.1 is needed by chromium-33.0.1750.152-2.el6.i686

but than I do:

rpm -qf /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.3.9
libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-2.el6.x86_64

Comment: @mario-viti: You should not normally mix `i686` and `x86_64` packages unless you are specifically running a mixed architecture system.  You are likely looking to install the `x86_64` version of `chromium`.  Please post a new question if you need assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't suffice that the file is on your system: it has to be installed by an rpm. Probably libapr was installed manually and not using an rpm. So either:

- uninstall libapr, and reinstall it with an rpm
- install your myrpm ignoring the fact that he can't find libapr (`rpm -i --nodeps`); but that is dangerous because the `--nodeps` switch will ignore ALL dependencies!